# Prove continuous of $f(x)$ where $x$ is rational and irrational

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFjJx.jpg)

Deﬁnition of continuous:. We say that a function $f$ is continuous at the point $x=a$ provided that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x − a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) − f(a)| < \varepsilon$.

Theorem :. The function $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $f$ satisﬁes the following property:

$\forall$ sequences $(x_n)$, if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a$$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(a).$$

Use above Theorem to show that[ $f(x) = x$, if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 0$, if $x$ is irrational ]

is not continuous at $a \neq 0$.

Hint [ there is two cases, first case when $a$ is rational, $f(a) = a$. Build a sequence of irrational, second case, when $a$ is irrational. How do we build a sequence of rationals converging to $a$?]

My answer on picture, could you please check it for me any comment needs?

Comment: For any $a\neq 0$, we can find a sequence of rationals converging to $a$ whose image converges to $f(a)$, and a sequence of irrationals converging to $a$ whose image converges to $0$.

Comment: @Elliot G, do you mean I want to find a sequence of rationals converging to a whose image converges to f(a), and a sequence of irrationals converging to a whose image converges to 0?.

Comment: Yes; then the function cannot be continuous (which value would it have at $a$?)

Comment: Your proof looks correct! Basically you are proving&using the following facts: for every real number $a$, there exists a rational sequence converging to $a$ and an irrational sequence using to $a$.

Comment: @ Greg Martin yes,I use this fact so I do not need to find a specific sequence of rationals converging to a whose image converges to f(a), and a sequence of irrationals converging to a whose image converges to 0.?